# Program to synchronize folders between my PC and mobile by bluetooth

Tags: windows-xp, android, mobile-phone

Does anyone know any program to synchronize the files of a certain folder of my laptop with a certain folder in my android movile by bluetooth? I would like my bluetooth mobile phone automatically detect my laptop and synchronize my computer files that were within a certain folder of it with a certain folder of my mobile, previously set.

**EDIT**
By the way, my OS is WXP SP3.

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: @Mark: "...except insofar as they interface with your computer."

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: It might not be possible. See this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-to-share-files-through-bluetooth